# xCode - Why can't I see this object on the view?

Tags: objective-c, macos

This might be a silly question, but why in the world can't I see the the following button that I simply dragged and dropped to the view from the interface builder?

I am using Simulator iPhone Retina (3.5 inch) / iOS 7. When I try to scroll to the bottom, the scrolling ends and I cannot see the button that I placed at the bottom. Why is that? Thanks.

[image: This button is not visible in the simulator]

EDIT: I didn't do anything fancy. I simply created a new single view app, and then dragged the button to the bottom of the view on storyboard and then clicked run.

Comment: Have you set the autolayout constraints of the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storyboard simulate size of 4 inch display. When you run it on 3.5 inch display, content at the bottom of the screen will be clipped.
Just add constraints to attach button to bottom of the screen.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a newbie to objective-c and xcode. Didn't know that bit of info. Thanks. For anyone who wants to know just control-click from the object to the bottom edge empty space and select "Bottom space to bottom layout". Case closed. :)